# slideUp/slideDown Div's with same class using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create a one pager checkout form.

I need to slide up and slide down a few divs and all the divs have the same class name but the contents of the divs is different.

I have created this jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/gpjrh8zr/1/

and this is my jquery code:

```
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
$( ".pageContent" ).slideUp( "slow" );
},
function() {
$( ".pageContent" ).slideDown( "slow" );
});
```

as you can see, the code above will slideDown all the divs at once.

could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: `click` method doesn't accept 2 functions! And you should change the structure of the markup. The logic seems to be broken. How do you click an element when it's hidden?

Comment: I started to write an answer but then realized that I didn't understand what you wanted. What should a button click to, and how does it relate to the sliding up and down?

Comment: @j08691, have you seen a one pager checkout pages? the ones that slide up and down? basically, that is what I am trying to achieve .

Comment: @Vohuman, yeah I understand the logic is not right!

Comment: @j08691, AHHHH, that's the word i was looking for! accordion. yes mate.

Answer (score -2):

you can use :nth-of-type selector

```
function() {
$( ".pageContent:nth-of-type(4)" ).slideDown( "slow" );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gpjrh8zr/3/